# Error: Source GraphQL API: HTTP error 500 Internal Server Error Wordpress gatsby

Tags: wordpress, nginx, graphql, frontend

I have `Wordpress` on `Nginx` , and I want use `Gatsby` and `Graphql` , I installed `wp-graphql` and `wp-gatsby` in the panel
I have this problem : when run `gatsby develop` in client , I get this error , I don't know is it for Nginx or for plugin that installed in the gatsby ,

#### gatsby-config.js

```
plugins:[
{
 resolve: "gatsby-source-graphql",
      options: {
        typeName: "WPGraphQL",
        fieldName: "wpgraphql",
        url: "http://localhost/graphql",
      },
    },
```

#### Error in the running

```
"gatsby-source-graphql" threw an error while running the sourceNodes lifecycle:

Source GraphQL API: HTTP error 500 Internal Server Error



  Error: Source GraphQL API: HTTP error 500 Internal Server Error
  
  - fetch.js:11 exports.fetchWrapper
    [mammut-store]/[gatsby-source-graphql]/fetch.js:11:11
  
  - task_queues.js:97 processTicksAndRejections
    internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5
  

warn The gatsby-source-graphql plugin has generated no Gatsby nodes. Do you need it?
```

#### /etc/nginx/sites-available

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/wordpress;

        index index.php;

        server_name 127.0.0.1;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }

        location /graphql {
                proxy_pass http://localhost/graphql;
        }
}
```

This file is link with sites-enable/wordpress
And I run `nginx -t` for check nginx and it was true

#### Note :

In the client , `http://localhost:8000/___graphql` works correctly but not load my fieldName as wpgraphql ,  and when I open `localhost/graphql` I get 500 error

Comment: make `localhost/graphql` working first ... does graphql playground [in admin] work? queries/requests are going to .... what url/port? ... test API using Postman ... use gatsby after that

Comment: Thank you @xadm for your suggestion , I checked first playground in the panel , Requests worked correctly , But I check the url of graphql in devTool , I figure out , the url is `http://localhost/index.php?graphql` , I dont know is it usual or not , because I saw exp : localhost/graphql in the samples , thank you again

Comment: some nginx related problem ... like https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql/issues/213 ?